# Programmatically alter a BMP file

Tags: java, file, bmp

I want to load a bmp file (in Java) and manipulate the image data within the syntax of a java program. How can I do this? I tried just loading the image, like so:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("START");
            loadbitmap lbm = new loadbitmap();
            lbm.loadBMPFile();
            System.out.println("END");
        }

        private void loadBMPFile()
        {
            {
                try{

                    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("sample_fingerprint_grayscale.bmp");
                    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                    String inputString;
                    while ((inputString = br.readLine()) != null)   {

                        readBMPFile.add(inputString);
                    }
                    in.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    System.out.println("IN ERROR");
                    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
                System.out.println("IN loadBMPFile");
                System.out.println("BMP size is " + readBMPFile.size());
                System.out.println(readBMPFile.get(2));
            }
        }
}
```

But when I inspect the data, its not really there. I'm a noob at this, so any points in the right direction is appreciated.

Here is the output:

```
START
IN loadBMPFile
BM¸U

(At this point there is a large amount of gibberish characters that won't paste into Stack Overflow)

END
```

I have a hex reader(Frhed) that formats these characters into hex format, I was hoping I could bring them characters into an arraylist and manipulate them from there.

Here is the hex reader output:

````
BM<bh:b8>U<bh:01><bh:00><bh:00><bh:00><bh:00><bh:00>6<bh:04><bh:00><bh:00>(<bh:00><bh:00><bh:00><bh:f0><bh:00><bh:00><bh:00><bh:98><bh:fe><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:01><bh:00><bh:08><bh:00><bh:00><bh:00><bh:00><bh:00><bh:82>Q<bh:01><bh:00><bh:12><bh:0b><bh:00><bh:00><bh:12><bh:0b><bh:00><bh:00><bh:00><bh:00><bh:00><bh:00><bh:00><bh:00><bh:00><bh:00><bh:00><bh:00><bh:00><bh:00><bh:01><bh:01><bh:01><bh:00><bh:02><bh:02><bh:02><bh:00><bh:03><bh:03><bh:03><bh:00><bh:04><bh:04><bh:04><bh:00><bh:05><bh:05><bh:05><bh:00><bh:06><bh:06><bh:06><bh:00><bh:07><bh:07><bh:07><bh:00><bh:08><bh:08><bh:08><bh:00><bh:09><bh:09><bh:09><bh:00>


<bh:00><bh:0b><bh:0b><bh:0b><bh:00><bh:0c><bh:0c><bh:0c><bh:00>


<bh:00><bh:0e><bh:0e><bh:0e><bh:00><bh:0f><bh:0f><bh:0f><bh:00><bh:10><bh:10><bh:10><bh:00><bh:11><bh:11><bh:11><bh:00><bh:12><bh:12><bh:12><bh:00><bh:13><bh:13><bh:13><bh:00><bh:14><bh:14><bh:14><bh:00><bh:15><bh:15><bh:15><bh:00><bh:16><bh:16><bh:16><bh:00><bh:17><bh:17><bh:17><bh:00><bh:18><bh:18><bh:18><bh:00><bh:19><bh:19><bh:19><bh:00><bh:1a><bh:1a><bh:1a><bh:00><bh:1b><bh:1b><bh:1b><bh:00><bh:1c><bh:1c><bh:1c><bh:00><bh:1d><bh:1d><bh:1d><bh:00><bh:1e><bh:1e><bh:1e><bh:00><bh:1f><bh:1f><bh:1f><bh:00>   <bh:00>!!!<bh:00>"""<bh:00>###<bh:00>$$$<bh:00>%%%<bh:00>&&&<bh:00>'''<bh:00>(((<bh:00>)))<bh:00>***<bh:00>+++<bh:00>,,,<bh:00>---<bh:00>...<bh:00>///<bh:00>000<bh:00>111<bh:00>222<bh:00>333<bh:00>444<bh:00>555<bh:00>666<bh:00>777<bh:00>888<bh:00>999<bh:00>:::<bh:00>;;;<bh:00>\<\<\<<bh:00>===<bh:00>>>><bh:00>???<bh:00>@@@<bh:00>AAA<bh:00>BBB<bh:00>CCC<bh:00>DDD<bh:00>EEE<bh:00>FFF<bh:00>GGG<bh:00>HHH<bh:00>III<bh:00>JJJ<bh:00>KKK<bh:00>LLL<bh:00>MMM<bh:00>NNN<bh:00>OOO<bh:00>PPP<bh:00>QQQ<bh:00>RRR<bh:00>SSS<bh:00>TTT<bh:00>UUU<bh:00>VVV<bh:00>WWW<bh:00>XXX<bh:00>YYY<bh:00>ZZZ<bh:00>[[[<bh:00>\\\\\\<bh:00>]]]<bh:00>^^^<bh:00>___<bh:00>```<bh:00>aaa<bh:00>bbb<bh:00>ccc<bh:00>ddd<bh:00>eee<bh:00>fff<bh:00>ggg<bh:00>hhh<bh:00>iii<bh:00>jjj<bh:00>kkk<bh:00>lll<bh:00>mmm<bh:00>nnn<bh:00>ooo<bh:00>ppp<bh:00>qqq<bh:00>rrr<bh:00>sss<bh:00>ttt<bh:00>uuu<bh:00>vvv<bh:00>www<bh:00>xxx<bh:00>yyy<bh:00>zzz<bh:00>{{{<bh:00>|||<bh:00>}}}<bh:00>~~~<bh:00><bh:7f><bh:7f><bh:7f><bh:00><bh:80><bh:80><bh:80><bh:00><bh:81><bh:81><bh:81><bh:00><bh:82><bh:82><bh:82><bh:00><bh:83><bh:83><bh:83><bh:00><bh:84><bh:84><bh:84><bh:00><bh:85><bh:85><bh:85><bh:00><bh:86><bh:86><bh:86><bh:00><bh:87><bh:87><bh:87><bh:00><bh:88><bh:88><bh:88><bh:00><bh:89><bh:89><bh:89><bh:00><bh:8a><bh:8a><bh:8a><bh:00><bh:8b><bh:8b><bh:8b><bh:00><bh:8c><bh:8c><bh:8c><bh:00><bh:8d><bh:8d><bh:8d><bh:00><bh:8e><bh:8e><bh:8e><bh:00><bh:8f><bh:8f><bh:8f><bh:00><bh:90><bh:90><bh:90><bh:00><bh:91><bh:91><bh:91><bh:00><bh:92><bh:92><bh:92><bh:00><bh:93><bh:93><bh:93><bh:00><bh:94><bh:94><bh:94><bh:00><bh:95><bh:95><bh:95><bh:00><bh:96><bh:96><bh:96><bh:00><bh:97><bh:97><bh:97><bh:00><bh:98><bh:98><bh:98><bh:00><bh:99><bh:99><bh:99><bh:00><bh:9a><bh:9a><bh:9a><bh:00><bh:9b><bh:9b><bh:9b><bh:00><bh:9c><bh:9c><bh:9c><bh:00><bh:9d><bh:9d><bh:9d><bh:00><bh:9e><bh:9e><bh:9e><bh:00><bh:9f><bh:9f><bh:9f><bh:00><bh:a0><bh:a0><bh:a0><bh:00><bh:a1><bh:a1><bh:a1><bh:00><bh:a2><bh:a2><bh:a2><bh:00><bh:a3><bh:a3><bh:a3><bh:00><bh:a4><bh:a4><bh:a4><bh:00><bh:a5><bh:a5><bh:a5><bh:00><bh:a6><bh:a6><bh:a6><bh:00><bh:a7><bh:a7><bh:a7><bh:00><bh:a8><bh:a8><bh:a8><bh:00><bh:a9><bh:a9><bh:a9><bh:00><bh:aa><bh:aa><bh:aa><bh:00><bh:ab><bh:ab><bh:ab><bh:00><bh:ac><bh:ac><bh:ac><bh:00><bh:ad><bh:ad><bh:ad><bh:00><bh:ae><bh:ae><bh:ae><bh:00><bh:af><bh:af><bh:af><bh:00><bh:b0><bh:b0><bh:b0><bh:00><bh:b1><bh:b1><bh:b1><bh:00><bh:b2><bh:b2><bh:b2><bh:00><bh:b3><bh:b3><bh:b3><bh:00><bh:b4><bh:b4><bh:b4><bh:00><bh:b5><bh:b5><bh:b5><bh:00><bh:b6><bh:b6><bh:b6><bh:00><bh:b7><bh:b7><bh:b7><bh:00><bh:b8><bh:b8><bh:b8><bh:00><bh:b9><bh:b9><bh:b9><bh:00><bh:ba><bh:ba><bh:ba><bh:00><bh:bb><bh:bb><bh:bb><bh:00><bh:bc><bh:bc><bh:bc><bh:00><bh:bd><bh:bd><bh:bd><bh:00><bh:be><bh:be><bh:be><bh:00><bh:bf><bh:bf><bh:bf><bh:00><bh:c0><bh:c0><bh:c0><bh:00><bh:c1><bh:c1><bh:c1><bh:00><bh:c2><bh:c2><bh:c2><bh:00><bh:c3><bh:c3><bh:c3><bh:00><bh:c4><bh:c4><bh:c4><bh:00><bh:c5><bh:c5><bh:c5><bh:00><bh:c6><bh:c6><bh:c6><bh:00><bh:c7><bh:c7><bh:c7><bh:00><bh:c8><bh:c8><bh:c8><bh:00><bh:c9><bh:c9><bh:c9><bh:00><bh:ca><bh:ca><bh:ca><bh:00><bh:cb><bh:cb><bh:cb><bh:00><bh:cc><bh:cc><bh:cc><bh:00><bh:cd><bh:cd><bh:cd><bh:00><bh:ce><bh:ce><bh:ce><bh:00><bh:cf><bh:cf><bh:cf><bh:00><bh:d0><bh:d0><bh:d0><bh:00><bh:d1><bh:d1><bh:d1><bh:00><bh:d2><bh:d2><bh:d2><bh:00><bh:d3><bh:d3><bh:d3><bh:00><bh:d4><bh:d4><bh:d4><bh:00><bh:d5><bh:d5><bh:d5><bh:00><bh:d6><bh:d6><bh:d6><bh:00><bh:d7><bh:d7><bh:d7><bh:00><bh:d8><bh:d8><bh:d8><bh:00><bh:d9><bh:d9><bh:d9><bh:00><bh:da><bh:da><bh:da><bh:00><bh:db><bh:db><bh:db><bh:00><bh:dc><bh:dc><bh:dc><bh:00><bh:dd><bh:dd><bh:dd><bh:00><bh:de><bh:de><bh:de><bh:00><bh:df><bh:df><bh:df><bh:00><bh:e0><bh:e0><bh:e0><bh:00><bh:e1><bh:e1><bh:e1><bh:00><bh:e2><bh:e2><bh:e2><bh:00><bh:e3><bh:e3><bh:e3><bh:00><bh:e4><bh:e4><bh:e4><bh:00><bh:e5><bh:e5><bh:e5><bh:00><bh:e6><bh:e6><bh:e6><bh:00><bh:e7><bh:e7><bh:e7><bh:00><bh:e8><bh:e8><bh:e8><bh:00><bh:e9><bh:e9><bh:e9><bh:00><bh:ea><bh:ea><bh:ea><bh:00><bh:eb><bh:eb><bh:eb><bh:00><bh:ec><bh:ec><bh:ec><bh:00><bh:ed><bh:ed><bh:ed><bh:00><bh:ee><bh:ee><bh:ee><bh:00><bh:ef><bh:ef><bh:ef><bh:00><bh:f0><bh:f0><bh:f0><bh:00><bh:f1><bh:f1><bh:f1><bh:00><bh:f2><bh:f2><bh:f2><bh:00><bh:f3><bh:f3><bh:f3><bh:00><bh:f4><bh:f4><bh:f4><bh:00><bh:f5><bh:f5><bh:f5><bh:00><bh:f6><bh:f6><bh:f6><bh:00><bh:f7><bh:f7><bh:f7><bh:00><bh:f8><bh:f8><bh:f8><bh:00><bh:f9><bh:f9><bh:f9><bh:00><bh:fa><bh:fa><bh:fa><bh:00><bh:fb><bh:fb><bh:fb><bh:00><bh:fc><bh:fc><bh:fc><bh:00><bh:fd><bh:fd><bh:fd><bh:00><bh:fe><bh:fe><bh:fe><bh:00><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:00><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff><bh:ff>
````

Comment: Have you considered the BMP file's header?
And it's not a good way to read BMP's by *line* s.

Comment: Show us a sample output.

Comment: @FlopCoder I have considered the header. My plan was to determine where the image data starts in the file and just manipulate it from there within the array. To your second point, I am beginning to understand that reading the BMP into a string array may not be a good approach. I've googled it for a while and I can't find how to read in the BMP data so I can change it. Most of the google results concern getting the image loaded to display, which isn't what I need. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: @CodeBlue Sample output provided. It looks like its loading the data, but its not in hex form its in character form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [javax.imageio.ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html).

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("... .bmp"));
```

A BufferedImage may be altered too, so quite suitable for modifying.